# loop over files in a directory conditional on date in directory name (Mac os - zsh)

Tags: macos, zsh

I have a directory structure Year-month-date name:

```
2021-05-02 Linus
2021-04-02 Jay
2021-07-03 Sara
```

etc...

Now I´d like to loop over all directories with month <6 and run a script. Without the condition I do the following, but cannot figure out how to condition..

```
for f in ./*;  do  (cd "$f";  printf "file '%s'\n" *.csv>mylist.txt ); done;
```

Mac OS Big Sur with zsh

Comment: Wonderful—just what i was looking for. Copy-paste as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ISO8601-style dates really simplify situations like this. Try this glob pattern:

```
for f in ./2021-0[1-5]*;  do
  (cd "$f";  printf "file '%s'\n" *.csv > mylist.txt)
done
```